# How to Make the Open recent do-files list longer

Tags: stata

If one goes to the File menu of the `Do-file` Editor window of Stata, one sees that one of the options is `Open recent do-files`. Is it possible to control how many entries appear in this list? I would like to see more than the 10 that are currently there.

Within Stata, I looked in Preferences

> General Preferences - Windows - Do-file Editor

in both General and Advanced and did not see a place to control this.

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280853/texshop-open-recent-menu-not-working) question is somewhat related to the one here

Comment: Assuming you are running Stata 14 for Mac (since the previous thread you cited was a Mac-based example), I reviewed `com.stata.stata14.plist` and could find no obvious preference that would set the size of the 10-element array containing recently opened do-files. That is, all the preferences with values of "10" were font sizes. :-(

Comment: Yes, Stata 14 for Mac. Thanks for looking!

Comment: Perhaps it's controlled (across all apps on your Mac) by the "Recent Items" setting in the General tab of System Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a question regarding the macOS rather than Stata.  If you open up the System Preferences in you mac and navigate to the General options, you will see an option with a line starting "Recent Items: " As in the screen shot below.

If you change that setting and relaunch Stata it should work.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this in a Windows environment.

[image: Mac System Preferences, General, recent items]